# Proper way to initialize a string in C

Tags: c, string, char

I've seen people's code as:

```
char *str = NULL;
```

and I've seen this is as well,

```
char *str;
```

I'm wonder, what is the proper way of initializing a string? and when are you supposed to initialize a string w/ and w/out NULL?

Comment: You are not initializing a string in the code shown. You are intializing a pointer to a character.

Answer (score 15):

You're supposed to set it before using it. That's the only rule you *have* to follow to avoid undefined behaviour. Whether you initialise it at creation time or assign to it just before using it is not relevant.

Personally speaking, I prefer to never have variables set to unknown values myself so I'll usually do the first one unless it's set in close proximity (within a few lines).

In fact, with C99, where you don't have to declare locals at the tops of blocks any more, I'll generally defer creating it until it's needed, at which point it can be initialised as well.

Note that variables are given default values under certain circumstances (for example, if they're static storage duration such as being declared at file level, outside any function).

Local variables do not have this guarantee. So, if your second declaration above (`char *str;`) is inside a function, it may have rubbish in it and attempting to use it will invoke the afore-mentioned, dreaded, undefined behaviour.

The relevant part of the C99 standard `6.7.8/10`:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
> - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules.

Comment: char const s[] = "Nice answer";

Answer (score 5):

> I'm wonder, what is the proper way of initializing a string?

Well, since the second snippet defines an *uninitialized* pointer to string, I'd say the first one. :)

In general, if you want to play it safe, it's good to initialize to `NULL` all pointers; in this way, it's easy to spot problems derived from uninitialized pointers, since dereferencing a `NULL` pointer will yield a crash (actually, as far as the standard is concerned, it's undefined behavior, but on every machine I've seen it's a crash).

However, you should not confuse a `NULL` pointer to string with an empty string: a `NULL` pointer to string means that that pointer points to nothing, while an empty string is a "real", zero-length string (i.e. it contains just a `NUL` character).

```
char * str=NULL; /* NULL pointer to string - there's no string, just a pointer */
const char * str2 = ""; /* Pointer to a constant empty string */

char str3[] = "random text to reach 15 characters ;)"; /* String allocated (presumably on the stack) that contains some text */
*str3 = 0; /* str3 is emptied by putting a NUL in first position */
```

Comment: Uh oh, modifying a string literal. Undefined behavior :)

Comment: Watch better: `str2` (which points to a string literal) is not modified, and `str3` is allocated on the stack (or somewhere else, depending on where that code is put), the literal is just for initialization.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You're pointing str3 to a string literal and then modify the contents of the pointer. Don't.

Comment: Nope. `str3` is an array, not a pointer! The literal is used for initialization, it's *copied* in the buffer (`str3`), which is automatically sized by the compiler to accommodate that string. Look e.g. here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w7xccx8%28VS.80%29.aspx.

Comment: @EboMike: `str3` has type `char[]` which becomes complete once it is initialised with the string literal to `char[38]`. This type is a modifiable lvalue. You are not modifying the string literal, you are modifying an lvalue that has the same type and contents as the string literal.

Comment: @EboMike: §6.7.8: [8] An initializer specifies the initial value stored in an object. [14] An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the character string literal (including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array. [22] If an array of unknown size is initialized, its size is determined by the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer. At the end of its initializer list, the array no longer has incomplete type.

Comment: Agh... I *should* have looked closer!

Comment: _in this way, it's easy to spot problems derived from uninitialized pointers, since dereferencing a NULL pointer will yield a crash_: Several year ago, I would have agreed with you, but now there are powerful tools that detect the usage of uninitialized memory. By initializing all pointers (or even all variables) with a generic value before setting the pointer/variable to the _real_ value, we disable an import part of the code analysis of compilers (static code analysis) and valgrind (dynamic). They will not be able to detect usage of the variable before it got the _real_ value. +1 for @martin

Comment: @hagello: if we were talking about initializing int variables I'd agree with you, but here we are talking about pointers - dereferencing a NULL pointer is a good recipe for a loud crash, and is handled just fine by static analyzers and valgrind as well; also, when looked at in a memory dump it's way clearer than random garbage (although, the "freed memory" patterns are even better in this respect). Besides, having valgrind or serious static analyzers is often a luxury - most of the development I do requires cross-compiling, and there you are lucky if you have a remote gdb working.

Answer (score 4):

this is a general question about c variables not just char ptrs.

It is considered best practice to initialize a variable at the point of declaration. ie

```
char *str = NULL;
```

is a Good Thing. THis way you never have variables with unknown values. For example if later in your code you do

```
if(str != NULL)
 doBar(str);
```

What will happen. str is in an unknown (and almost certainly not NULL) state

Note that static variables will be initialized to zero / NULL for you. Its not clear from the question if you are asking about locals or statics

Comment: wow - you're a tough audience; i wonder what was wrong with this answer (which is the same as all the others)

Comment: Maybe you said "best practice" rather than "good practice"?  I don't know, I don't see how what you said justifies that down vote.

Comment: This clutters up code with a bunch of worthless setting and checking of pointer values.

Comment: @EdwardHartnett, no it doesnt. I did not advocate any checking of anything. I advocated getting into the habit of initializing at the point of declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are initialized with default values by a compiler, but local variables must be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

an unitialized pointer should be considered as undefined so to avoid generating errors by using an undefined value it's always better to use

```
char *str = NULL;
```

also because

```
char *str;
```

this will be just an unallocated pointer to somewhere that will mostly cause problems when used if you forget to allocate it, you will need to allocate it ANYWAY (or copy another pointer).

This means that you can choose:

- **if you know that you will allocate it shortly after its declaration you can avoid setting it as** `NULL` (this is a sort of rule to thumb)
- in any other case, if you want to be sure, just do it. The only real problem occurs if you try to use it without having initialized it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on how you're going to use it. In the following, it makes more sense *not* to initialize the variable:

```
int count;
while ((count = function()) > 0)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't initialise all your pointer variables to NULL on declaration "just in case".

The compiler will warn you if you try to use a pointer variable that has not been initialised, except when you pass it by address to a function (and you usually do that *in order to* give it a value).

Initialising a pointer to NULL is not the same as initialising it to a *sensible* value, and initialising it to NULL just disables the compiler's ability to tell you that you *haven't* initialised it to a sensible value.

Only initialise pointers to NULL on declaration if you get a compiler warning if you don't, or you are passing them by address to a function that expects them to be NULL.

If you can't see both the declaration of a pointer variable and the point at which it is first given a value in the same screen-full, your function is too big.

Comment: "The compiler *will* warn you". Let me rephrase: "The compiler will warn you about something *IF* you ask it to warn you about that thing."

Answer (score 1):

```
static const char str[] = "str";
```

or

```
static char str[] = "str";
```

Answer (score 1):

Because free() doesn't do anything if you pass it a NULL value you can simplify your program like this:

```
char *str = NULL;

if ( somethingorother() )
{
    str = malloc ( 100 );

    if ( NULL == str )
        goto error;
}
```

...

```
error:

cleanup();
free ( str );
```

If for some reason somethingorother() returns 0, if you haven't initialized str you will
free some random address anywhere possibly causing a failure.

I apologize for the use of goto, I know some finds it offensive. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet is a variable definition with initialization; the second snippet is a variable definition without initialization.

The proper way to initialize a string is to provide an initializer when you define it. Initializing it to NULL or something else depends on what you want to do with it.

Also be aware of what you call "string". `C` has no such type: usually "string" in a `C` context means "array of [some number of] char". You have pointers to char in the snippets above.

Assume you have a program that wants the username in argv[1] and copies it to the string "name". When you define the `name` variable you can keep it uninitialized, or initialize it to NULL (if it's a pointer to char), or initialize with a default name.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char name_uninit[100];
    char *name_ptr = NULL;
    char name_default[100] = "anonymous";

    if (argc > 1) {
        strcpy(name_uninit, argv[1]); /* beware buffer overflow */
        name_ptr = argv[1];
        strcpy(name_default, argv[1]); /* beware buffer overflow */
    }

    /* ... */

    /* name_uninit may be unusable (and untestable) if there were no command line parameters */
    /* name_ptr may be NULL, but you can test for NULL */
    /* name_default is a definite name */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By proper you mean bug free?  well, it depends on the situation.  But there are some rules of thumb I can recommend.

Firstly, note that strings in C are not like strings in other languages.

They are pointers to a block of characters.  The end of which is terminated with a 0 byte or NULL terminator. hence null terminated string.

So for example, if you're going to do something like this:

```
char* str;  
gets(str);
```

or interact with str in any way, then it's a monumental bug.  The reason is because as I have just said, in C strings are not strings like other languages.  They are just pointers.  char* str is the size of a pointer and will always be.

Therefore, what you need to do is allocate some memory to hold a string.

```
/* this allocates 100 characters for a string 
   (including the null), remember to free it with free() */
char* str = (char*)malloc(100);
str[0] = 0;

/* so does this, automatically freed when it goes out of scope */
char str[100] = "";
```

However, sometimes all you need is a pointer.
e.g.

```
/* This declares the string (not intialized) */
char* str;

/* use the string from earlier and assign the allocated/copied
   buffer to our variable */
str = strdup(other_string);
```

In general, it really depends on how you expect to use the string pointer.
My recommendation is to either use the fixed size array form if you're only going to be using it in the scope of that function and the string is relatively small. Or initialize it to NULL.  Then you can explicitly test for NULL string which is useful when it's passed into a function.

Beware that using the array form can also be a problem if you use a function that simply checks for NULL as to where the end of the string is.  e.g. strcpy or strcat functions don't care how big your buffer is.  Therefore consider using an alternative like BSD's strlcpy & strlcat. Or strcpy_s & strcat_s (windows).

Many functions expect you to pass in a proper address as well.  So again, be aware that

```
char* str = NULL;
strcmp(str, "Hello World");
```

will crash big time because strcmp doesn't like having NULL passed in.

You have tagged this as C, but if anyone is using C++ and reads this question then switch to using std::string where possible and use the .c_str() member function on the string where you need to interact with an API that requires a standard null terminated c string.

Comment: `gets` is a monumental bug whether you allocate the space or not :-)

Comment: Just nitpicking here, but when talking about the terminating null character it is best not to use the all-caps `NULL` since it introduces ambiguity with the null pointer constant, which is a fundamentally different concept altogether.

Comment: @paxdiablo: The latest draft of C1X introduces `gets_s` as a replacement to `gets`, obviously taking an additional parameter specifying the size of the buffer.

Comment: Hmm, not sure how useful that is, especially if it's just an interface layer to `fgets(...,stdin)`. They should have just deprecated `gets` then removed it totally from c2x :-)

Comment: I never actually use gets. What I'm attempting to demonstrate is that much of the C library doesn't like you to pass in NULL or 0L.