# How can i fixed this

Tags: c

I want to print String in a array.

```
#include "stdio.h"

    int main(){
        char str[201];
        /*scanf("%[^\n]", str);*/
        printf("%s\n", str);
        const char* A[26] = {"A", "B", "X", "P", "Q", "R", "M", "N", "C", "E", "D", "K", "L", "J", "O", "S", "H", "T", "U", "F", "V", "Z", "G", "W", "I"};
        printf("%s\n", A[5]);
    }
```

but output is

[image]

Comment: Why did you comment out the `scanf` and thus print using a buffer containing garbage?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: `printf("%s\n", str);` this is printing garbage value and `printf("%s\n", A[5]);` is printing `R` at the end(next line). as shown in output image.

Comment: What's wrong ? You are currently printing, as you said, string in your array.
The printed garbage is the content of your uninitialized `str` array.

Comment: You cannot 'const char* A[26] = {"A", "B", "X", "P"...}' try 'const char* A[] = {"A", "B", "X", "P"...}'

Comment: @Himanshu, is perfectly encrypted, what a clever compiler :)

Comment: @AlterMann, hahaha thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The garbage value being printed is because of un-initiallized `str`.

Use the commented `scanf` line and it will work fine.

or if you don't want to use that line, I would suggest you to initiallize your `str` like you did for `A`

Answer (score 0):

Well this is quite basic.

The value being printed is garbage as, whenever you print a un-initialized string in most languages, the output is garbage, because when you declare a string of lets say 10 chars, there is just 10 bytes allocated on the stack. No specific value is put in it.

Well it looks like the output you are getting is encrypted. (thanks to Alter Mann comment).

But, when you read a string using `fgets`, `scanf` or any other function, it doesn't matter if it is un-initialized or not. Whatever value is entered by the user, it gets stored in the string. So un-commenting your `scanf` will lead to the perfect output. If you have commented the `scanf` because you do not want to use it,  just initialize it like:

```
char str[201] = {"a", "b"};
```

and put whatever you want to.

Also, I am not sure if this is a good way, so check this: [Proper way to initialize a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083239/proper-way-to-initialize-a-string-in-c)

**Basically**, if you do not want to read the complete answer, the output is perfectly correct, as you have not initialized a string and the `R` you get is stored in `A[5]`, which you print.